# Get many onenote pages content

Tags: graph, onenote

I have an app which reads the page content of a onenote notebook which I'm currently doing one page at a time. This takes about twenty seconds. I've had a good look through the docs but I can't find a way to retrieve the content of multiple (say 20) pages at once. Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CTRL-A, followed by CTRL-C > CTRL-V (or CMD-A > CMD-C > CMD-V on a Mac). This will allow you to copy a whole page of content, then paste it somewhere else.

Comment: I'm using the MS Graph API from my App to access OneNote. I'm not using the MS OneNote client or Web interface.